# 2-day ahead prediction of value at risk with GARCH(1,1) in R

Tags: programming, time-series, value-at-risk, garch

Let's say I have a 10 year dataset of Tesla (example) and I am taking the percentage change of lag 2:

```
tsla <- quantmod::getSymbols("TSLA", from = base::as.Date("2011-01-01"), to = base::as.Date("2022-01-31"), auto.assign = F)
tsla = as_tibble(tsla)
head(tsla)
d = tsla%>%
  dplyr::select(TSLA.Adjusted)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(Close = TSLA.Adjusted)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(y = as.numeric((Close - dplyr::lag(Close, 2)) / Close))%>%
  dplyr::select(Close,y)%>%
  tidyr::drop_na();d
```

That look like this:

```
# A tibble: 2,786 × 2
   Close        y
   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  5.37  0.00783
 2  5.58  0.0434 
 3  5.65  0.0499 
 4  5.69  0.0200 
 5  5.39 -0.0475 
 6  5.39 -0.0553 
 7  5.24 -0.0282 
 8  5.15 -0.0470 
 9  5.13 -0.0226 
10  4.81 -0.0716 
# … with 2,776 more rows
```

Now I want to fit the GARCH(1,1) model with normal innovations.

```
garnor1 = function(x){
  require(fGarch)
  t = length(x)
  fit = garchFit(~garch(1,1),data=x,trace=F,cond.dist="norm")
  m = fit@fitted
  cv = fit@sigma.t
  var = m+cv*qnorm(0.01) # low tail 
  return(var[t])
}
```

What I have succeeded is that I can estimate the the lower value at risk for 2-day returns up to time $t$. This will give a number that is the VaR up until now (say today). Am I right until now?

If yes, I know that the VaR is being calculated from the predictive function for the $t+2$ quantile value. Doing so I have to predict the above function:

```
g11pre = function(x){
  require(fGarch)
  fit = garchFit(~garch(1,1),data=x,trace=F,cond.dist="norm")
  df=coef(fit)["shape"]
  p = predict(fit,2)
  m=p$meanForecast
  cv=p$standardDeviation
  var=m+cv*qnorm(0.01)
  return(var[2])
}
```

And this last predictive function I have to backtest or the previous one?

**Edit**

For the backtesting in the predictive function I tried something by my own.(in order to fully understand it):

```
db=  d%>%
dplyr::mutate(back_lower = zoo::rollapplyr(y,252,FUN = g11pre,by = 21,fill=NA))%>%
  tidyr::fill(back_lower)%>%
  tidyr::drop_na()
```

I know it looks strange.Let me explain.I am using the full 10 year dataset.The period of estimation are the first 252 days and then roll by one month (21) days.I am not interested on by 2 day assess-roll the model.
Plotting the backtesting result:

```
p = ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = db, aes(x =1:length(y) , y = y), color = "black") +
  geom_line(data = db, aes(x = 1:length(back_lower), y = back_lower), color = "red") +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('risk low')
```

That looks like a step graph (this what It must look like)

[image]

Comment: i am calculating the percentage change in lag 2

Comment: no worries, was very logic to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general, forecasting Value at Risk (VaR) following a parametric GARCH framework follows standard practices of univariate (point) forecasting.** Moreover, we are always interested in the accuracy of a VaR model based on the out-of-sample forecast performance.

## Forecasting 2-day ahead Out-of-sample Value at Risk:

Assume that we are standing at time $t$ with information $\mathcal{F}_t$, then for a constant mean model $\mu$, we can define a univariate GARCH(1,1) framework for a return process $r_{t+1}$ as:

\begin{align*}
r_{t+1} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t} &= \mu + \varepsilon_{t+1}\\
\varepsilon_{t+1} &= \sigma_{t+1} \cdot z_{t+1}\\
\sigma^2_{t+1} &= \omega + \alpha_1 \varepsilon_{t}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t}^2,
\end{align*}
where $z_t \overset{iid}{\sim} D(0,1)$ (*which in your case is the Gaussian distribution*). It is the standardized distribution of the innovations, $z_t$, that determines the quantile in the forthcoming parametric VaR equation. Then the VaR at time $t+1$ given the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ can be defined as (*equivalent to the 1-step ahead VaR*):

$$
VaR_{t+1\vert t}^\alpha = \mu + \sigma_{t+1\vert t}\cdot\Phi^{-1}_\alpha\left(0,1\right)
$$
Note that in some cases we negate the above calculation, in order to get positive VaR estimates. This makes sense when taking about losses in notional amount. **Nevertheless the 2-step ahead VaR forecast can be obtained via a recursive forecasting scheme:**

$$
VaR_{t:t+2\vert t}^\alpha = \mu + \sigma_{t:t+2\vert t}\cdot\Phi^{-1}_\alpha\left(0,1\right), \tag{1}
$$
where we observe that the only forecastable object in the Gaussian VaR framework is the conditional volatility process. Note that the 2-step ahead conditional volatility forecast, $\sigma_{t:t+2\vert t}$, is recovered by utilizing the prediction at time $t+1$. Using the fact that the multistep recursive forecast for the GARCH(1,1) is given by (*see [this link](https://www.kevinsheppard.com/files/teaching/mfe/notes/financial-econometrics-2020-2021-chapter-7.pdf) p. 449*):

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_{t+h}^2 \vert \mathcal{F}_t\right] = \sum_{i=0}^{h-1} (\alpha_1 + \beta_1)^i \cdot \omega + (\alpha_1+\beta_1)^{h-1}(\alpha_1 \varepsilon_t^2+\beta_1 \sigma^2_t)
$$

we get for $t+2$:

\begin{align*}
\sigma^2_{t:t+2\vert t}&:=\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_{t+2}^2 \vert \mathcal{F}_t\right] \\
&= \omega + (\alpha_1 + \beta_1) \mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_{t+1}^2\vert \mathcal{F}_t\right]\\
&= \omega + (\alpha_1+\beta_1)\omega + (\alpha_1+\beta_1) \alpha_1 \varepsilon_t^2 + (\alpha_1+\beta_1) \beta_1 \sigma_t^2.
\end{align*}
Inserting this in $(1)$ yield the 2-step ahead VaR forecast/prediction in the GARCH(1,1) framework. **Now you can do the following recursive procedure to acquire your forecasts:**

1. Fit the GARCH(1,1) model via a rolling or expanding window,
2. get estimates $(\hat{\omega},\hat{\alpha}_1, \hat{\beta}_1, \hat{\mu})$ at each time point $t$,
3. calculate the 2-step ahead VaR forecast, $VaR_{t:t+2\vert t}^\alpha $.

### Alternative approach:

Instead of the above methodology, you could fit the GARCH(1,1) model on **sparse sampled returns** which are sampled every second day, ie. $\{r_t,r_{t+2},r_{t+4},\ldots\}$.

This will yield conditional volatilities every second day. **Then the 1-step ahead VaR forecast,$VaR_{t+1\vert t}^\alpha$, defined in $(1)$** gives you a VaR estimate for the next 2 days.

This methodology is easy to implement as you can follow most literature on how they define the 1-step ahead forecast without the need of additional derivations. **For this matter, you can get some inspiration from the `R` code provided [here](https://rpubs.com/ionaskel/VaR_Garch_market_risk)** (*however, they only estimate VaR in-sample, not out-of-sample)*.

---

If you want to specify a time-varying mean model $\mu_t$, then you also need the 2-step ahead conditional forecast of $\mu_{t+2\vert t}$ in order to recover your VaR forecasts. These can very often get recovered using a similar recursive scheme. **I hope this provide some insight.**

Comment: Thank you for answer first of all.The 2-day lag is a real world time lag problem that I am facing.I am just trying some volatility models in order to assess a risk factor that passes the backtesting procedure.So if I have understood from your answer I have to backtest the second predictive function in my OR.Am I right?If not please provide some correction code if necessary.Also can you please provide me the name of the book ? Thank again.

Comment: Currently, I am very busy. However, I will provide an alternative approach to forecasting two-step ahead VaR and then I will link to some R-code that looks promising. I will make an edit soon.

Comment: No rush.Thanks a lot.I will be waiting.

Comment: Given your model, the notation of the following part seems questionable: *Nevertheless the 2-step ahead VaR forecast can be equivalently specified as: ...*. In the context of your model, your $\sigma_{t+2|t}$ is the conditional standard deviation of return from $t+1$ to $t+2$ but the OP seems to be interested in the return from $t$ to $t+2$ instead.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, I want to make an edit specifying that you can do an alternative approach to forecasting, where you fit your GARCH model to every second day returns $r_t, r_{t+2},\ldots$ implying that the original 1-step ahead VaR forecast will predict 2 days ahead, hence from $t$ to $t+2$.

Comment: That is also fine, but what I meant was specifically the problem with notation in your current approach. But this is just a tiny thing, otherwise a helpful answer.

Comment: I made an edit with the backtesting procedure

Comment: So i have understood the forecast horizon is not in days but in period.?Suppose i had monthly data returns the one step ahead forecast $t+1$ will be the forecast for the next month.Right?But i didn;t get the forecast for the mean.Why here changes ?

Comment: @HungryHomer Yes, the forecast horizon is denoted in periods that follows the periodicity of the original process. Eg. if you had daily returns then one-step ahead forecast $t+1$ denotes the next day. If you had monthly returns, then $t+1$ denotes the next month etc. My last comment in the answer, was just for you to understand, that if you want to specify a time-varying mean model (eg. an AR model) then you need to find the conditional forecast for this aswell. It was just an extended comment and have nothing to do with your current problem. You can disregard it, if it causes confusion. :-)

Comment: Then if in the predictive function in `garchFit` the argument `include.mean=TRUE` was included then the `predict(fit,1)` will contain the 2 days ahead forecast not only for the volatility but for the mean as well.Right?

Comment: @HungryHomer It will estimate the constant mean $\mu$. The constant mean will not change for different forecast horizons, since the expectation of a constant is the constant itself. But yes, the predict function will contain the forecast for both the constant mean and the time-varying volatility model.

Comment: Right.So far this is in the conditional framework of volatility forecasting.It is the same for unconditional ?I will make new question.

Comment: you can see it [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/70202/backtesting-conditional-versus-unconditional-forecast-horizon-with-lag-2)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be whether to evaluate/backtest in-sample VaRs or out-of-sample VaRs. I presume you want to get a sense of your model's anticipated performance on unseen future data. If your model was exactly correct, both ways would be fine. However, in reality models are not exactly correct. Then out-of-sample VaRs are the relevant ones, as they (unlike the in-sample VaRs) mimic how you will be using your model.

Just note that if your 2-day periods overlap, your effective sample size is half of what the nominal sample size is. (I cannot tell from your code whether you only look at every second day or at every day. It is in the latter case that the neighboring 2-day returns will overlap.)

Comment: 2-day period is a real world time lag so it is of my interest.I want to fit many models and then from the backtesting to assess  their performance in the loopback period.But my question remains.The predictive function (second R's function) is that to be backtested ? Right?

Comment: @HungryHomer, yes, I think so.